# MODULE MASKED IN PYSPARK . NOT ACCESSIBLE

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am a novice to Pyspark. I was trying to run a pyspark code. I ran a code with name "time.py" because of which the pyspark is not able to run now. I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/VAL_CODE/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext,HiveContext,SparkConf
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.3-1.cdh6.3.3.p0.1796617/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 14, in <module>
    from time import time as _time, sleep as _sleep
  File "/home/VAL_CODE/time.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name SparkContext
20/08/13 19:04:16 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/08/13 19:04:16 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f104da1f-ba70-4c45-8a19-6ffc55b609aa
```

The error is that the script "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py" is referring to the local script "/home/VAL_CODE/time.py" which I created. Now, I have deleted the "/home/VAL_CODE/time.py" script. But still face the issue when I run a new code "/home/VAL_CODE/test.py". Please help to resolve.

Comment: have you removed `time.pyc` as well?

Comment: Yes. I removed this and it worked fine. Thanks @Alex Ott